# static function is not a function javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a simple class

```
class EngineSwitchboard {

static routePacket(packet) {
    console.log("got it !")
    console.log(packet)
    return
}

}

module.exports.EngineSwitchboard = EngineSwitchboard;
```

and a simple call ..

```
const EngineSwitchboard = require("./engine_switchboard");  
packet = "hello world"
EngineSwitchboard.routePacket(packet)
```

i am getting an error EngineSwitchboard.routePacket is not a function. Thanks for any help, but I think i am close to a couple of tutorials i found that should work.

Comment: `module.exports = EngineSwitchboard;`   Or call like -> `EngineSwitchboard.EngineSwitchboard.routePacket(packet)`   But I think the first option is better.. :)

Comment: Alternate: `const EngineSwitchboard = require("./engine_switchboard").EngineSwitchboard` (**not sanctioned**)

Comment: Alternate: `const { EngineSwitchboard } = require("./engine_switchboard");` ;)

Comment: Thanks much for your help, gents!